# Using Landing Pages as custom Preference Center

Tags: marketing-cloud, custom-profile, landing-page

I am hoping to create a custom profile page using landing pages and ampscript.  I understand how to pull subscriber data into the form, but I am wondering what is the best method to submit form data back into an existing profile on landing pages.  Is doing a WebCollect call my only option or is there a better way to submit the page and process the form input?

Thanks,

Comment: I would take a look at the below link to get you started.  Using AMPScript and the SOAP API will allow you to make calls to ExactTarget to pass those  updates through.

http://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/technical_library/web_service_guide/technical_articles/creating_a_custom_profile_center_using_ampscript_and_the_soap_api/

Comment: While this link is interesting, my solution has to be achieved strictly with landing pages.  It is my understanding you can use AMPscript but not SOAP API calls on landing pages.  My situation doesn't otherwise provide a server environment capable of API calls -hence landing pages.

Comment: Now that I have reviewed the link and achieved some progress, I am assuming this AMPscript is technically using using API calls (or at least equivalent functionality).  Regardless I seem to be on track updating subscriber data.  I wish there was a more baseline explanation on how this works, but so far this page is the best resource out there. Thanks! (How does one mark a question as answered?)

Answer (score 1):

If you use a Smart Capture form in the Landing Page you can then take a look at the *Processing* tab in the WYSIWYG editor. The *Processing* tab will have all of the AMPscript it created to load the form submission into the list or data extension. You could then modify that form for your use case by editing the generated AMPscript.